# Parsing JSON performance

Tags: android, android-json

I have json with some objects in it. And only one object from json i need. So which approach will be better for speed and performance - parse only this object or parse whole document instead?

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil ;) Do whichever one requires less coding, and make a note of it. If you run into a bottleneck later on, then you can switch it.

Comment: This is my bottleneck, i parse whole data and get 7-8 seconds delay, before i got all needed data.

Comment: Ouch. Yeah that's pretty bad. Have you tried the other way? That should answer your question.

Comment: No, i don't. 7-8 second that's from 18 different URLs. So there is a third approach - if i make more threads to parse data. It's gonna help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show only the particular JSON Object which may be either inside a JSON Object or JSON array itself then you just parse that particular JSON Object instead of parsing whole document.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use rest of the data, you can just parse the item you only need.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, just the object would get you a result faster with lesser work times. So just parse the object you need.